# Add number to numbers inside a text python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Add number to numbers inside a text python:

Input:
 `Sono stata 21 commossa che lei ci ha 45 letto`

Output:
 `Sono stata 22 commossa che lei ci ha 46 letto`

My code:
`text_after = re.sub("^[0-9]+", "^[0-9]+"+1, text)`

Comment: can you post all your code please?

Comment: You cannot use regular expressions to do mathematical operations. You could use it to extract the number from the text to a variable, add +1, then replace the number with regex

Comment: Just use a `re.sub` with a callable as replacement argument. `re.sub(r'\d+', lambda x: str(int(x.group())+1), s)`.  See https://ideone.com/dX1C96